# How to make a matrix using index and the value in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, crosstab

I have a dataset, which has two columns:

```
index  Value 

0      True

1      True

2      False

3      True
```

Is it possible to obtain a matrix that looks like

```
index  0   1   2  3

0    True  True False True   

1    True  True False True

2    False False False False

3     True True False True
```

I tried `pd.crosstab`, still not able to get the matrix, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

A possible way:

```
m = np.tile(df['Value'], len(df)).reshape(-1, len(df)) * df[['Value']].values
out = pd.DataFrame(m)
print(out)

# Output
       0      1      2      3
0   True   True  False   True
1   True   True  False   True
2  False  False  False  False
3   True   True  False   True
```

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the values of `Value` columns to a numpy array using `to_numpy`. Then take advantage of numpy broadcasting by creating an extra axis with `[:,None]` and computing the bitwise and operation:

```
vals = df['Value'].to_numpy()

res = pd.DataFrame(vals[:,None] & vals, index=df.index)
```

Output:

```
>>> res

           0      1      2      3
index                            
0       True   True  False   True
1       True   True  False   True
2      False  False  False  False
3       True   True  False   True
```